# Global variables in bootstrap.js in Firefox for Android extensions

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, firefox-addon, global-variables

I want to know if it's right (allowed and without side effects) to use global variables in  the `bootstrap.js` file of a Firefox extension (Firefox for Android), especially when these variables may contain the  `Document` object, and are used by event listeners and observers. And if it's not can you explain the risks, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bootstrap.js` scope is yours and yours alone. Go berserk with global variables, if you like (however, maintainability is another issue ;)

Having said that, be careful when stuffing references to other scopes (windows, other modules) into variables of any kind, as this may leak (or since Firefox 15 throw exceptions when accessing dead `window`s and associated `documents`s). The other way round, stuffing references to your stuff, can be problematic as well. Read [Common causes of memory leaks in extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Common_causes_of_memory_leaks_in_extensions).

Add-ons, and restartless add-ons in particular, have to clean up after themselves!

Comment: ok, I see. I read the article about the memory leaks and I wonder can the use of "Services.scriptloader.loadSubScript" cause a memory leak, since I looked if there s a way to unload the script and I found [this](http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2011/01/restartless-add-ons-more-resources/) (that you recommanded to me once)but it doesn't seem to mention the scriptloder.